# Why there are $n^{n}$ possible arrangments?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I found this problem:

Suppose $n$ balls are distributed into $n$ boxes so that all of
the $n^{n}$ possible arrangements are equally likely. Compute the probability
that only box 1 is empty.

Why there are $n^{n}$  possible arrangments?

If for the first box can be $0,1,2...,n$ balls($n+1$ possibilities).

For the second box $0,1,2,...,n-1$ balls ($n$ possibilities)

And so on..

So it must be $(n+1)!$ possible arrangements. Right?

Comment: If $n=1$ the number of arrangements is $1$.  Your formula gives $2!=2$.

Comment: The box with one ball and with no ball?

Comment: What?  you said the balls are distributed into the boxes.  Did you mean something different?

Comment: In the problem says that a box can be empty. Should I take empty boxes as part of arrangements?

Comment: Of course a box can be empty..if there are more than one boxes!!

Comment: Suppose the balls are numbered $\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$.  Then there are $n$ places to place $b_1$, $n$ places to place $b_2$, and so on.  That's how you get to $n^n$. Of course there are $n!$ ways to place them such that no box is empty.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, that is very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I don't go into chat rooms.

Comment: As for a hint on how to proceed with the actual problem, recognize that exactly one of the boxes will have two balls and every other box (other than box1) will have one ball each.  Pick which box has two balls and which two balls they are.  Permute the remaining balls amongst the boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the $n^n$ thing, I suggest this way. We'll build a PROCESS, then apply the multiply rule. Notice that the result you provide only true when all the balls are **distinguishable** and all the boxes are also **distinguishable**.

Since each of the balls must be arranged in a box, we'll build a process, in which each ball will be put in the boxes in an order. N

There are $n$ ways to put the first ball into the boxes (you can put it in the first box, the second box,... or the n-th box)

Similarly, there are $n$ ways to put the second ball, ... and the n-th ball into the boxes.

Since the way you put the i-th ball is not related to the way you put the j-th ball, thus we can apply the multiply rule, and get the desired result

P.s: I might have made some lexical mistakes, as my English is not good.

Answer (score 1):

"$n$ balls *distributed* into $n$ boxes" has a bunch of different interpretations.
a) **uniformly randomly throw** *undistinguishable*  balls into $n$ *distinguishable* boxes: for each ball you have $n$ choices, for $n$ balls they total to $n^n$.
a')**uniformly randomly throw** *distinguishable*  balls into $n$ *distinguishable* boxes: same as before.

That's because by *throwing* we are normally assigning a equiprobable space to the events ($k$th ball picked, $j$th box hit) and not to the resulting configuration (ball,box): actually some of these latter configurations will be repeated. So it is like we pick a ball and mark it according to the lauching sequence (whether or not it was already marked by other means).

b) **uniformly random filling** (I don't know the standard denomination) of *un/distinguishable* boxes with *un/distinguishable* balls. Now the equiprobable events are considered to be the each *"different configuration"* of the (ball,boxes), which depend on the four mixing  possibilities of un/distinguishable.

Note that the case b), with distinguishable (marked) balls and distinguishable boxes does not correspond to a), since we pass from b-dd) to a) by ranking the balls in each box according to their marking: the ball launched first will always be lower in the box (figured as a can of piled balls).